# Adobe Reader: Text hidden/invisible in pdf files

Tags: pdf, adobe

I am working on an MFC Application which downloads text data from a remote location and create reports of that text and save it to Local File system .
When I open the .pdf file , screen is white i.e all text is hidden/invisible.

Although, when I place the cursor on the white screen. I can select the invisible text.
I copied this text to some text file. The data is appropriate.

Is this any known issue? I searched a lot but did not get any answer?

This is a link to my test file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0lm1XPE9vc_ZkRmRVEzN2drYTg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: On a semi-related note, making text visible only on screen, or only when printing [is supported by the PDF format](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/enterpriseplatform/10.0/DesignerHelp/WS107c29ade9134a2c583558f12a7dc955d9-8000.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your PDF page has dimensions far beyond the limits PDF Reader are expected to be able to display. Its media box is defined as

```
/MediaBox[0 0 41052376 848.68]
```

i.e. it has a size of 41052376 x 848.68 user space units.

The PDF specification, on the other hand, says:

> conforming readers should accommodate PDF files that obey the constraints.
>
> - ...
> - The minimum page size should be 3 by 3 units in default user space; **the maximum should be 14,400 by 14,400 units.**

Your width of 41052376 units is far beyond those 14400 units PDF Readers are expected to accommodate.

Having patched your file to use a page size of 410.2376 x 848.68 Adobe Reader displays it just fine:

[image: Adobe Reader screen shot displaying PDF with reasonable page dimensions]

Comment: okay.
How to solve it?
Can this be solved by some configurations in the Adobe Reader installed in my computer?

Comment: Create PDF files which at least try to follow the recommendations from the PDF specification. Your PDF uses values in the PDFs which make it a gamble whether any PDF processing software accepts it or not. And the jagPDF library you use to create the PDFs can be told to create PDF pages with proper dimensions

Comment: Oh it means there is a fault in my MFC Application that is not creating the right type of pdf file. Thanks mkl.